# how comparing PQG with PEG and PQA in Blast Algorithm?

Tags: bioinformatics

In BLAST algorithm with seed stage 
   the score obtained by comparing PQG with PEG and PQA is 15 and 12, respectively. 
 I dont' understand this . can any body explain with example how  comparing PQG with PEG and PQA is 15 ?
  it is very important

Answer (score 3):

The scores are calculated using (apparently) the [BLOSUM62](http://www.uky.edu/Classes/BIO/520/BIO520WWW/blosum62.htm) substitution/scoring matrix.

To calculate the total score between two k-mers, refer to the matrix to find the scores between their individual (aligned) amino acids and sum them.

So, comparing:
PQG with
PEG

we have:

P:P >> 7 +
Q:E >> 2 +
G:G >> 6
= 15

Similarly, for PQG and PQA:

P:P >> 7 +
Q:Q >> 5 +
G:A >> 0
= 12